# How can we check if a password doesn't exist in the DB?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, passwords

I developing a web app in PHP 7 and MySQL 5 following the MVC design pattern. I'm working on the registration system and there I'm facing a problem with password_verify method. Indeed, I would to check if a password does not exist in the DB before inserting user's profile. Here is my code :

```
 public function signUp($name, $firstname, $profilePicture, $phone, $email, $password, $passwordConfirmation)
    {
        $userData = $this->_userDAO->getUsersDataByEmail($email);
        if (isset($name) && isset($firstname)
            && isset($profilePicture)
            && isset($phone) && isset($email)
            && isset($password) && isset($passwordConfirmation)) {
            if ($userData == false) {
                if (password_verify($password, $userData["password"]) == false) {
                    if (preg_match("/^0[1-9]([0-9]{2}){4}$/", $phone)) {
                        if (preg_match("/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@\/+=!?&*#<>_]).{8,}$/", $password)) {
                            if ($password == $passwordConfirmation) {
                                $this->_userDAO->addUser($name, $firstname, $profilePicture, $phone, $email, password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
                                $this->_membersDAO->addMember();
                                header("Location:index.php");
                            } else {
                                echo "Les mots de passe ne se correspondent pas, veuillez réssayer s'il vous plaît !";
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo "Votre mot de passe doit contenir au moins un chiffre, une lettre minuscule, une majuscule ainsi qu'un 
                     symbole spéciale et être d'une longueur supérieure à 8 caractères !";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "Veuillez saisir un numéro de téléphone valide !";
                    }
                    } else {
                    echo "Le mot de passe saisie est déjà utilisé ! Veuillez en choisir un autre !";
                }


            } else {
                echo "L'email saisie est déjà utilisé, veuillez en saisir un autre !";
            }

        }
    }

   public function getUsersByEmail($email)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email = ?";
        $userEmail = $this->queryRow($sql, $email);

        return $userEmail;
    }

public function addUser($name, $firstname, $profilePicture, $phone, $email, $password)
{
    $column = ["name", "firstname", "profile_picture", "phone", "email", "password"];
    $values = ["'$name'", "'$firstname'", "'$profilePicture'", "'$phone'", "'$email'", "'$password'"];
    $this->insertRow("users", $column, $values);
}

public function queryRow($sql, $param = null) { 
try { 
$request = $this->request($sql, $param); 
$data = $request->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$request->closeCursor(); } 
catch (PDOException $e) { 
die("Erreur : " . $e->getMessage()); } 
return $data; 
}
```

However, when I execute the script, the user's data is registered while the password entered by the user already exist in DB.

Could you help me to solve this problem please ?

Comment: Why does it matter if two users have the same password?

Comment: What does `queryRow` do/return?

Comment: I know that two users can have same password with two different email but I want to make all the user unique enforcing the registration system rules.

Comment: All of the passed in parameters will be set/declared, so none of those `isset()` calls are necessary.  If you are checking for `null` values, that can be done without function calls.  `/^0[1-9]([0-9]{2}){4}$/` is more simply expressed as `/^0[1-9]\d{8}$/`.  `addUser()` looks doomed to break when a value contains a single-quote.

Comment: If you are now saying that two users can have different emails, but same passwords, then that seems correct ...but that now makes your question Unclear.  Please do not add question details as comments; all relevant details should be in the question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all but I've solve my problem. I'm gonna change my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use php's password hashing system, you cannot use SQL to decide whether a password is unique.  Why not? the hashing system applies a random *salt* to each password. The purpose of this salt is, fundamentally, to make it impossible to compare one password to another without using [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) on *every password in your database.*  The way php and password-hashing work, that will take about 250ms for each password. That is a prohibitive amount of time. That's the point: hashing  and verifying passwords is, deliberately, a cpu-intensive process, to  slow down cybercreeps.

Generally, every user should be able to choose their own password. If you tell a user a particular password already exists in your system, it's a security violation.

I've never heard of a system that enforced password uniqueness (and I've heard of many systems).  You do need to enforce username uniqueness, whether by using  email addresses for usernames, or by rejecting pre-existing usernames.

When you create a new user, simply use [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) on that password to obtain the value to put in the user's row in your database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've changed my code to enforce email uniqueness only.